# Mysql import statement not affecting database

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm trying to get an .sql file imported to a database on my MySql server on linux. I've run the command

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < file_location
```

...but nothing seems to happen. When I run the command, it asks for my password, I put it in, and the command is supposedly run (I don't see any results or messages). I know it's not working because I log into the MySql server and check the database and there's nothing there. Anybody know what's going on?

I tried to add the verbose option but I got a bunch of errors, or what I think are errors. Here are a few of the first lines:

```
--------------
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
--------------

--------------
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */
--------------

--------------
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */
--------------

--------------
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */
--------------

--------------
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */
--------------

--------------
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */
--------------

--------------
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */
--------------
```

Comment: Try testing with -verbose switch as mysql -u root -p -v database_name < file_location

Comment: I tried that, and now I'm just getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: Could you post the error details?

Comment: It's really long, is there a way to post files?

Comment: Try editing the question and post the first few lines may be.

Comment: Done, you can see the changes now

Comment: These are just log statements, not errors. If you can post some errors here they can help pointing out the problem.

Comment: That's all there is. I don't know where errors would be if there are any.

Comment: If this is all the output you get, then that means that nothing is happening. What is the script for? Do you have phpmyadmin installed on the linux server?

Comment: I do not. I sorta tried to start to install it, but I didn't get very far

Comment: Can you post contents of your sql file?

Answer (score 0):

Run your script with `-vvv` option to get an echo of each query executed.

```
mysql -vvv -u root -p database_name < file_location
```

Comment: It just has alot of what I originally posted, what I thought were errors

Answer (score 0):

I have it fixed. Somehow the file got corrupted and I just re-downloaded it. Thanks for the help